# Powershell script for running a command on a bunch of files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run this command:

`java -cp "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.4\plugins\java-decompiler\lib\java-decompiler.jar" org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler -hdc=0 -dgs=1 -rsy=1 -rbr=1 -lit=1 -nls=1 -mpm=60 (source) (dest)`

On a few hundred files nested into folders.

I can dig out the files with

`dir -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ProjectZomboid" -Recurse -Include *.class`

I figured if I pipe it into a ForEach-Object I can do this:

`dir -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ProjectZomboid" -Recurse -Include *.class | ForEach-Object -Process {java -cp "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.4\plugins\java-decompiler\lib\java-decompiler.jar" org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler -hdc=0 -dgs=1 -rsy=1 -rbr=1 -lit=1 -nls=1 -mpm=60 "$_"}`

This gives me an error because of no destination though. Almost there. I've got the (source) down, now I need the (dest) to be formatted correctly and go from:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ProjectZomboid\zombie\SandboxOptions.class

to

.\zombie\

Basically replace 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ProjectZomboid' by a . and remove the file name.

That's the hard part that I can't figure out.

Edit: thanks to both answers I was able to write a complete command! There may be a better way but it works.

`dir -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ProjectZomboid" -Recurse -Include *.class | ForEach-Object -Process {java -cp "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.4\plugins\java-decompiler\lib\java-decompiler.jar" org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler -hdc=0 -dgs=1 -rsy=1 -rbr=1 -lit=1 -nls=1 -mpm=60 $_ ($_.PSParentPath.ToString().Replace('Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ProjectZomboid', '.') + '\')}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\Users\Claus\Tools\JGPSTrackEdit' -Recurse -Include *.jar  
| ForEach-Object -Process { java -jar $($($_.ToString()).Replace('C:\Users\Claus\Tools\JGPSTrackEdit', '.'))}
```

Instead of dir, I user Get-ChildItem, and as I am a noob in java and haven't got a java-decompiler, I just executed the jar.

*ToString* converts the path object $_ to a string object. only then you can do a replace.

*Replace('C:\Users\Claus\Tools\JGPSTrackEdit', '.')* replaces the path with a dot.

I hope it is clear how it should work from this example.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dir -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ProjectZomboid" -Recurse -Include *.class |
```

ForEach-Object -Process {java -cp "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.4\plugins\java-decompiler\lib\java-decompiler.jar" org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler -hdc=0 -dgs=1 -rsy=1 -rbr=1 -lit=1 -nls=1 -mpm=60 $*.PSPath  $*.PSParentPath}

ParentPath is the entire filespec minus the filename.